# filter metacharacters from user input in xss attack

Tags: php, xss

on my site on the admin login page if i do something like this

```
http://www.domain.com/admin/index.php/%22onclick=document.location="http://www.google.com">
```

and click somewhere the page actually redirects. i read somewhere that i need to filter metacharacters. but after hours of googling i cant find out how i can stop this. the above from what i see isnt doing a get or post. how can i block something like this?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are you saying you're entering that and it creates a link with that URL, or are you saying you're typing that into the browser?

Comment: And how is a raw query parameter getting embedded into your page. Are you doing something like `echo $_GET`? Never ever take raw user input and use it for output.

Comment: @marc, i was doing <?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> in the forms action. i finanlly found out that i had to do something like <?php print htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> instead.  @Cfreak, i entered it into the browsers url.

Comment: PHP_SELF should never be used for just this reason - it contains the raw user-supplied query string, which as you can see, is utterly vulnerable to hacking.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do any character filtering / massaging. What you need to do is treat ALL user input, regardless of how it was sent to you, as an evil virus and handle it as such.

How is this link being generated? Is this something you wrote or something another user put into some sort of CMS?

I'm not sure there is enough information to directly help you but you should never redirect WITH any data a user passes to your page. Instead, use the information they pass to determine where they should go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that there is something seriously wrong with your script if it executes arbitrary JavaScript passed in to the QUERY_STRING, or any parameter for that matter.

The "do this to handle 80% of the threats" thing to do is to write a scrubInput() function that substitutes % & ; < and > to [their respective metacharacter codes](http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/).  This does not include all attack vectors on things that get stored in the database, but the ; will take care of a lot of those.